# CPVC - any health concerns?

Tags: cpvc

We are considering a new construction where the builder has used cpvc pipes for hot and cold water. Are there any health concerns? Internet search is mostly negative. Anyone has any thoughts or experience?

Comment: Out of curiosity, where is this house that CPVC is used in?  It is common in your area?

Comment: This is in IL - Chicago suburbs.

Answer (score 2):

Aside from a few crackpots, which the internet is rife with, if the pipe is rated for **potable water use** (and it almost certainly is) it's unlikely to pose any actual health concern. That is the NSF/ANSI 61 standard, and is typically marked on the pipe as "NSF-PW" in the string of identification that's printed on the exterior. For plastic pipes, NSF/ANSI 14 is also applicable.

If you resemble believing those crackpots to any degree, it's easy enough to either put your drinking and cooking water through extra filtration or slightly less easy to haul it in or have it delivered.

Answer (score 2):

[CPVC](http://216.169.121.148/upload/literature/CPVC.asp) systems are chemically inert to most mineral acids, bases and salts, as well as aliphatic hydrocarbons. In addition, these systems are not subject to galvanic corrosion.
Which means that nothing in the CPVC dissolves into or reacts with your water or anything else already dissolved in your water.

So unless you're worried about having it [catch fire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chlorinated_polyvinyl_chloride#Fire_properties), you'll be fine.
But if your plumbing is on fire you have bigger problems ...